execute apache-airflow on a remote server
i have a linux server that has apache airflow installed and hosted on it, on the other hand i have a windows server that contains all the dags, i created a connection between the dags folder on the linux machine and the dags folder on windows, and the dags show up as normal on the ui, my problem is that running the dags runs it on the linux machine, which does not have the requirements nor the database connections needed to run the dags, is it possible to make the execution happen only on the windows machine?
im thinking of creating a worker on the windows machine and have it listen on some queue where if i run the add it adds it to the queue
